# Simple way to explain semicolons

Tags: javascript

My wife is working her way through Codecademy (Javascript) and was frustrated by semicolons. She asked me which lines need to end in semicolons. She's just starting out so I didn't want to scare here with "statements", "expressions", etc. I just told her to not bother with semicolons, it is JS after-all ;)

So how should I have explained it?

Comment: Semi-colons go on the: `1.` right side of an assignment. `2.` function calls. `3.` Expressions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Semi-colons end each thing.
2. You don't want it right after `if(test)` because then it ends that thing (indeed - it's not invalid, you just really don't want to end it right there). Likewise with `for(a;b;c)` (but each thing inside the `for`  is a thing).
3. `x = 2 + 1 + 3 + 4 + 5 * 10 + 2;` is a single thing, or you wouldn't have the whole sum. Even over three or four lines, you want it to be a single sum - a single thing.
4. Braces group a few things into one big thing. Since they're already a thing with an end, they don't need a semi-colon. But it won't hurt.

Comment: +1 for covering the braces with so much detail, but the first point could do with some addition. `end each thing` as in, if you have an operator at the end of the line or the next line utilizes the return value of the previous, then you can't "end" it or it'll break.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté That's a good elaboration upon "thing". The balance with these things is always between vague enough to convey the gist, while not so imprecise as to cause more confusion than you solve. (And why I like, "okay, here's the vague idea" to be followed with "okay, here's the precise rules" sooner rather than later, before bad habits kick in).

Comment: Yup, I see. My elaboration wasn't very elaborated though, it doesn't cover function declaration/expressions and the like. But your explanation of `thing` should be enough to give a basic concept as OP requested.

Comment: It is very important to learn the basics, she should learn the different types of statements and which need to end in a semicolon. It's not really that hard. Use JSLint as a learning tool (learn to ignore or tolerate its nit-picks).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes, at some point you have to throw all this away and go, "right, here's the exact rules".

Answer (score 1):

The simple rule is that all statements must end in a semicolon. Things like expressions, blocks and function declarations don't end in semicolons. Maybe the following helps.

Blocks don't end with semicolons:

```
if ( /*condition */ ) { // start of block, no semicolon
  ...                   // function body
}                       // end of block, no semicolon
```

The same is true for other blocks such as *do..while*, *while*, *for..in*, and so on.

Function declarations don't have semicolons (they use blocks):

```
function foo() { // start of block
  ...            // code, may be statements with semicolons and more blocks
}                // end of block, no semicolon
```

Things that look like blocks but aren't:

```
// Object literal isn't a block, it's a statement so uses {}
var obj = {name: 'fred', sex: 'male'};

// Object literal over several lines has one semicolon at the end
var obj = {
    name: 'fred',
    sex: 'male'
};
```

Function expression as a statement:

```
(function(){...}());  // expression in (), the
                      // terminating semicolon makes it a statement
```

Over several lines:

```
(function(){  // Start of block (function body) doesn't use semicolon
    ...
 }()          // block end, no semicolon.  Can't end statement here
              // (unbalanced parenthesis) so no semicolon after ()
);            // but end of statement does need semicolon
```

Note that function expressions can be just expressions.

e.g. function call passing the result of calling a function expression (note semicolon terminated statements in the function expression body):

```
foo( (function(){alert('hey'); return 'ho';}()) );

function foo(s) {
  alert(s);
}
```

To test if a semicolon is needed, remove the line break between two lines of code:

```
var a = 'foo';
alert(a);
```

Remove line break:

```
var a = 'foo'; alert(a); // works
```

remove semicolon:

```
var a = 'foo' alert(a); // fails
```

Comment: do...while does end with a semicolon.

Comment: Ooops, [my bad](http://es5.github.com/#x12.6.1), though it seems it can be omitted (at least in Firefox and IE9).

Comment: It can be omitted at the end of the line, as with most semicolons.

Comment: @JonHanna—browsers tolerate `do{}while(false) var i=3;` which, it seems to me, they should not. Or automatic semicolon insertion is a bit more sophisticated than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

My Javascript is a little rusty, but I believe you can get away with:
Every line unless it already ends with } or {. Then just make sure each statement is on a new line, though given the original question I'm assuming it's not an issue.

And not ending lines in semi-colons is a bad idea. There are certain cases where it won't actually work.

#### edit

In almost all cases it should be fine, and the articles posted in another answer are a good read about it, however I still stand by my love for semi colons*.